# Regex to get individual function bodies from group of functions

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a javascript file [`file.js`] containing a group of functions. The code looks something like this:

```
/**
 * Description 1
 * @param arg_1 {String}
 * @marked
 * @return {String}
 */
function func_1(arg_1)
{
    var test_var = arg_1.replace(/(?=[\\^$*+?.\(\)|{\}[\]])/g, "\\");
    return test_var;
}

/**
 * Description 2
 * @param arg_1 {String}
 * @notmarked
 * @return {String}
 */
function func_2(arg_1)
{
    var test_var = arg_1.replace(/(?=[\\^$*+?.\(\)|{\}[\]])/g, "\\");
    return test_var;
}

/**
 * Description 3
 * @param arg_1 {String}
 * @marked
 * @return {String}
 */
function func_3(arg_1)
{
    var test_var = arg_1.replace(/(?=[\\^$*+?.\(\)|{\}[\]])/g, "\\");
    return test_var;
}
```

Notice the JSDoc tags `@marked` and `@notmarked`.

The task I need to accomplish is to add comments to each function that has a `@marked` tag.

So a code block that was this:

```
/**
 * Description 1
 * @param arg_1 {String}
 * @marked
 * @return {String}
 */
function func_1(arg_1)
{
    var test_var = arg_1.replace(/(?=[\\^$*+?.\(\)|{\}[\]])/g, "\\");
    return test_var;
}
```

Becomes this:

```
/**
 * Description 1
 * @param arg_1 {String}
 * @marked
 * @return {String}
 */
//start
function func_1(arg_1)
{
    var test_var = arg_1.replace(/(?=[\\^$*+?.\(\)|{\}[\]])/g, "\\");
    return test_var;
}
//end
```

The major stumbling block is coming up with a suitable regex [regular expression] to isolate the functions properly so I can do a regex replace.

I have tried this regex:

```
@marked[^\^]*?\*\/[^\^]*?(function[^\^]*?\{[\S\s]+?\})
```

which is getting the two function matches, but it is stopping short of closing the full function body because there is closing bracket (}) in the body itself. And changing `[\S\s]+?` to `[\S\s]+` just pulls in everything to the last function's closing bracket.

Is this regex fixable, or there's a better way of accomplishing the task?

**EDIT**

The answer by [@rv7](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10078895/rv7) solved the issue. However, depending on how your function is setup, you might run into more problems.

For example, if you have a function block like this:

```
/**
 * Description 1
 * @param arg_1 {String}
 * @marked
 * @return {String}
 */
function func_1(arg_1)
{
    var test_var = arg_1.replace(/(?=[\\^$*+?.\(\)|{\}[\]])/g, "\\");
    var close_b = '}';
    var sub_func = function(){

    };
    return test_var;
}
```

The regex in the answer will not work. However, the following regex will:

```
@marked[^\^]*?\*\/[^\^]*?(function[^\^]*?\{[\S\s]+?[^\\\']\} *(?!;))
```

So, it's best to tweak based on your setup. All tolled, you should gun for the free-standing closing bracket, because that should be definitive for most function blocks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `[^\\]` just before `\}` in your regex to accomplish your task, which says:

> Find a `}` which is not preceded by a `\`, or syntactically which isn't escaped

Now, the regex becomes:

```
@marked[^\^]*?\*\/[^\^]*?(function[^\^]*?\{[\S\s]+?[^\\]\})
```

[Live Example](https://regex101.com/r/r8GvuW/1)

---

It can be further simplified as:

```
@marked[\s\S]*?(function[\s\S]*?[^\\]\})
```

[Live Example](https://regex101.com/r/x6S0XF/1)

---

**EDIT:**

For a more general solution, you can use `[;\s]` just before `\}`.

Comment: Amazing that it was just a little tweak! Thanks for the quick response and explanation. I noticed a few edge cases that I fixed using your approach, but will add it as an edit to the question. Cheers.

Comment: Welcome! I'm glad I could help you.